# svnlook cat -t not working on windows (when I was creating .bat script)

Tags: batch-file, transactions, cat, pre-commit, svnlook

I'm trying to write a .bat script as the pre-commit hooks in svn. However when I was trying to use the svnlook cat command with the -t option, it's not working. It kept telling me syntax errors. I tried everything including adding quotes, changing the -t option etc. However, if I remove the -t option, it doesn't report syntax errors. 
So this is the error scripts:

```
SET REPOS=%~1 (I want to remove the quotes of the path)
SET TXN=%2 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.exe" cat -t %TXN% %REPOS% myworkingdir/txtIwanttoread
```

If I do the following, they are all fine:

```
SET REPOS=%~1 (I want to remove the quotes of the path)
SET TXN=%2 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.exe" cat %REPOS% myworkingdir/txtIwanttoread
```

OR

```
SET REPOS=%~1 (I want to remove the quotes of the path)
SET TXN=%2 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.exe" cat -r 28 %REPOS% myworkingdir/txtIwanttoread
```

Somebody please help me!! Thanks!

Never mind everybody, I think I just figured it out myself. We should use SET TXN=%~2 to eliminate the quotes. Also even if I did that, the stupid batch puts a space at the end of the variable TXN. This is what causes the problem. So the script should look like:

```
SET REPOS=%~1 (I want to remove the quotes of the path)
SET TXN=%~2 
SET TXN=%TXN: =% (deblank)

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnlook.exe" cat -t %TXN% %REPOS% myworkingdir/txtIwanttoread
```

Comment: You could answer your own question and mark it as accepted, rather than just edit the answer into the question. This way you get the points and the question does not remain"unanswered" in the SO database....